# Add asociated array to the Values retrieved before

Tags: attributes, category, product-list, array

I have this code, witch retrieves the values I need:

```
<?php foreach($allProducts as $p): ?>
 <?php if(!$p->isSaleable()) continue; ?>
 <?php $out=$p->getAttributeText($pAtt->getName()); ?>
 <?php $frontValues[$out]=$out; ?>
 <?php $colors=$p->getData(strtolower($pAtt->getName())); ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

This is the markup that places this to my page:

```
<li><a id="a-<?php echo $out ?>"><?php echo implode('</li><li>">', $frontValues); ?></a></li>
```

The problem is that the `echo $out` is retrieved only ones, but there are more items in the array and all of them get's the same value, witch is not good for me.

The problem is that I can't figure out, how to make an Asociated Array to the values of `$frontValaues` array and add accordingly assign the correct id to the retrieved item.

I tryed adding

```
<?php $colorValues[$colors]=$colors; ?>
```

in `foreach`, and then replicating the same implode method, like this:

```
<li><a id="a-<?php echo implode('', $colorValues); ?>"><?php echo implode('</li><li>">', $frontValues); ?></a></li>
```

but then this array is adding all the values to the ID.

How can I separate them? So the only correct retrevied value would be asociated to the `<a>`.

I'm quite a newby here, so any suggestion is welcome.

Thanks,

**Full code and working for anyone who may be interested in it**

```
                <div class="color">
                  <?php if($_product->isConfigurable()): ?>
                    <?php $attributes = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableAttributes($_product) ?>
                    <?php if(count($attributes)): ?>
                      <div>
                      <?php foreach($attributes as $att): ?>
                        <?php $pAtt=$att->getProductAttribute();
                          if ($pAtt->getFrontendLabel() != 'Color') continue;
                          //get the child products
                          $allProducts = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getUsedProducts(null, $_product);
                          $frontValues =array(); ?>
                        <div style="text-align:center;"><!--<?php echo $pAtt->getFrontendLabel() ?>-->
                         <ul>
                         <?php 
                            $output = array();
                            foreach($allProducts as $p){
                              if(!$p->isSaleable()) continue;
                              $output[$p->getAttributeText($pAtt->getName())] = array(
                                            'out' => $p->getAttributeText($pAtt->getName()),
                                            'color' => $p->getData(strtolower($pAtt->getName()))
                                          );
                            }
                         ?>
                          <?php foreach($output  as $key => $value) : ?>
                            <li><a id="a-<?php echo $value['color'] ?>"><?php echo $value['out'] ?></a></li> 
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                         </ul>
                        </div>
                      <?php endforeach ?>
                      </div>
                    <?php endif ?>
                  <?php endif ?>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your issue correctly but try

```
foreach($allProducts as $p){
  if(!$p->isSaleable()) continue; 
  $out = $p->getAttributeText($pAtt->getName());
  $frontValues[$out]=$out; 
  $colors=$p->getData(strtolower($pAtt->getName()));
  $colorValues[$out]=$colors; 
}


<?php foreach($frontValues  as $key => $value) : ?>
   <li><a id="a-<?php echo $colorValues[$key] ?>"><?php echo $value ?></li> 
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

or

```
$output = array();
foreach($allProducts as $p){
  if(!$p->isSaleable()) continue; 
  $output[$p->getAttributeText($pAtt->getName())] = array(
                'out' => $p->getAttributeText($pAtt->getName()),
                'color' => $p->getData(strtolower($pAtt->getName()))
              );
}

<?php foreach($output  as $key => $value) : ?>
   <li><a id="a-<?php echo $value['color'] ?>"><?php echo $value['out'] ?></li> 
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Hey, I tryed to change to your code and I got nothing. But I can see the logic in your code and I think you understood correctly. I've added full code for the items, so maybe there is something what's killing your code. Could you please see it above. Thanks,

Comment: Ok, this works, but not correctly. This array takes to the account the number of items are available with that color. For example: I have 5 pink shoes, then he show's 5 "Pink" colors. How to ignore it? So only 1 color of each would be added?

Comment: Please add an example of what you want the output to be (html format)

Comment: <li><a id="a-<?php echo $value['color'] ?>"><?php echo $value['out'] ?></li> this output is correct when rendered. But the thing is, that for each, takes into account the number of Items (different sizes) and then for everysize it gets a color. Please find a screenshot here: http://imgur.com/m0AoYzh

Comment: I think this should be modified to get not all configurable attributes, but only color: `<?php $attributes = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableAttributes($_product) ?>`

Comment: if that the case then make the color key a variable

Comment: Honestly I do not understand the issue or what the expected output should be, so it hard to help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18128/discussion-between-arturas-strazdas-and-r-s).

Comment: I simply want to get available product colors in a list with id's of the color. Example: `<li><a id="a-282">Black</a></li>`

Comment: and what do my current code output?

Comment: The output is ok, but it's repeated multiple times. Because the array is taking into account the number of Assosiated items. Please see this -> http://i.imgur.com/m0AoYzh.png

Comment: the reapeat of the items is equal to the number of available size in both color combinatios. So I see the Color icons, because for each color I have 5 different sizes. I need to eliminate sizes from here. I don't know witch line is getting sizes. I've placed the full code for this in the Question. Please take a look. THANK YOU VERY MUCH

Comment: are they the same id or same name?

Comment: Yes, all of them has a same ID and same color Name. Can you continue this discussion in Chat?

Comment: You code seem to be different form what i suggested, is the code about the current code you are using?

Comment: modified the code with one you've suggested.

Comment: change this `$output[]` to $output[$p->getAttributeText($pAtt->getName())]

Comment: THAAAANK YOU !!!! Now it's working.

Comment: The should be a more efficient  way of doing this

Comment: This is the only way I found... If you know any better way, please... Because I'm newby on the subject. Thanks.